# Multiple steps workflow in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, tdd, bdd

I'm developing an application in rails with cucumber.

The application includes a workflow that have multiple steps.

Some steps are

- A user import files (3 different files),
- Other user make make some checks to date that was imported,
- Other user input some parameter,
- Other user apply the parameter to the data that was imported,
- etc.

The steps must be executed in the correct order, and I is necessary to run all the previous steps in order to execute each one, for example to apply the parameter its necessary to have the data imported and the parameters defined.

My problem is how to build cucumber scenarios/features in this situation. 
I know that a scenario is not suppose to call all the previous scenario.But the only other idea that I have is to create a very long scenario performing all this steps, and that make sense because it will be a scenario with more than 2 hundred steps.

Any thought on a pragmatical way of implementing cucumber in this kind of situation?

Many Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you have to perform every thing every time.

Will every usage of your system include importing three files? Are there any cases where the user may only need to import two files? If the case is that there will always be three files imported, then you might abstract that step as

```
given the files are imported
```

Things that always have to be done may be combined into some generic setup. As the setup never changes, the details may not be necessary to mention explicit.

My experience though, is that at the beginning it is hard to separate scenarios and try to do too much in a few scenarios with many steps. If you don't see any other way, start there. Look at your scenario and see if they possible to separate into perhaps two independent scenarios. It may be possible to separate it into two scenarios that are independent. Next step would be to see if these two new scenarios are possible to divide into two smaller, independent scenarios. It happens that it is possible.

It is obviously always possible that Cucumber is not the tool you need. It is possible that you would be better off with a unit test framework.

Comment: Excelent. Thats is exactely what I was asking. Answering your question, yes, every usage of the system include importing three files.

Comment: Then I would probably not even mention it in the scenario. A bit like saying that you have to breathe when you use the program. Of course you have to breathe, but it's nothing we mention up in a scenario.